# Remove subsequence function (deep recursion) in scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, lisp, racket

Im trying to write a function called `removesub*` which accepts two arguments `(l1 and l2)`. The function needs to return the second list with the first occurence of the subsequence removed. So, if the first list is `'(a b c)`, the first `a` if the second list is removed, the first `b` that appears after the removed `a` is removed, and the first `c` that appears after the removed `b` is removed - no matter how deep the atoms are nested.

> Working Example
>
> Input: `(removesub* '(a b) '(w (x b) ((a) ((y z))) b a))`
>
> Output: `(w (x b) (() ((y z))) a)`

My current attempt doesnt seem to work because I have no way of sharing the l1 argument between nested recursive calls i.e. `((pair? (car l2)) (cons (removesub* l1 (car l2)) (removesub* l1 (cdr l2))))` splits l1 into two separate instances resulting in the following result. **How can I share the `l1` value so every recursive calls knows if the others have found the first instance of a value in `l1`?**

> Working Example
>
> Input: `(removesub* '(a b) '(w (x b) ((a) ((y z))) b a))`
>
> Output: `(w (x b) (() ((y z))) b)`

## Attempted Solution - Scheme

```
(define removesub*
  (lambda (l1 l2)
    (cond
      ((or (null? l1) (null? l2)) l2)
      ((pair? (car l2)) (cons (removesub* l1 (car l2)) (removesub* l1 (cdr l2))))
      ((eq? (car l1) (car l2)) (removesub* (cdr l1) (cdr l2)))
      (else (cons (car l2) (removesub* l1 (cdr l2)))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the resulting symbols to search for to the next iteration. THere are many ways to do this.

**You can use a compound return in the helper**

```
(define (removesub* elements-in-order haystack)
  ;; just use a pair to pass result and the 
  ;; elements to continue searching for
  (define (result eio h)
    (cons eio h))

  (cdr
   (let rec ((eio elements-in-order)
             (h haystack))    
     (cond ((or (not (pair? eio))
                (not (pair? h)))
            (result eio h))
           ((pair? (car h))
            (let* ((r (rec eio (car h)))
                   (r2 (rec (car r) (cdr h))))
              (result (car r2) (cons (cdr r) (cdr r2)))))
           ((eq? (car eio) (car h))
            (rec (cdr eio) (cdr h)))
           (else
            (let ((r (rec eio (cdr h))))
              (result (car r) (cons (car h) (cdr r)))))))))
```

Notice I do `car` first then use both parts of the result to do the next.

**Scheme/Racket can return more than one value with values**

```
(define (removesub* elements-in-order haystack)
  (define (helper eio h)    
    (cond ((or (not (pair? eio))
               (not (pair? h)))
           (values eio h))
          ((pair? (car h))
           (let*-values ([(eiocar hcar) (helper eio (car h))]
                         [(eiocdr hcdr) (helper eiocar (cdr h))])
             (values eiocdr (cons hcar hcdr))))
          ((eq? (car eio) (car h))
           (helper (cdr eio) (cdr h)))
          (else
           (let-values ([(eiocdr hcdr) (helper eio (cdr h))])
             (values eiocdr (cons (car h) hcdr))))))

  (let-values ([(eio result) (helper elements-in-order haystack)])
    result))
```

Not really a semantic difference over the first, but it might be a tad faster since in theory the results can stay on the stack rather than each result having to create a cons that can be GC-ed as fast as the stack unrolls.

**You can use continuation passing style:**

```
(define (removesub* elements-in-order haystack)  
  (let cps ((eio elements-in-order)
            (h haystack)
            (c (lambda (eio h) h)))    
    (cond ((or (not (pair? eio))
               (not (pair? h)))
           (c eio h))
          ((pair? (car h))
           (cps eio
                (car h)
                (lambda (eio hcar)
                  (cps eio
                       (cdr h)
                       (lambda (eio hcdr)
                         (c eio (cons hcar hcdr)))))))
          ((eq? (car eio) (car h))
           (cps (cdr eio) (cdr h) c))
          (else
           (cps eio
                (cdr h)
                (lambda (eio res)
                  (c eio (cons (car h) res))))))))
```

This works by the helper has a continuation argument. This is close to what many Scheme implementations actually do to your code before running.

**You can use mutation**

Probably the fastest and easiest, but then you need to use `#!r6rs`  or another standard Scheme rather than `#!racket` as implementation language.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is the meaning of your argument names in CPS style? Is `eio` equivalent to `l1` and `haystack` equivalent to `l2`?

Comment: @stack_pooper Yes. I find `l1` and `l2` to be bad names since it then looks that the arguments just are similar lists. In fact the first is a list of what to search for and the second is the source in which the result is built. Also if I would write code for  myself I would shadow my variables in the named let (ei. using the same names) but when I was learning Scheme I found the shadowing confusing.

Comment: Why `(or (not (pair? eio))
               (not (pair? h)))` instead of `(or (not (null? eio))
               (not (null? h)))` in CPS style?

Comment: @stack_pooper if the first term doesn't match you know for sure both `eio` and `h` are pairs. If you do `(or (null? eio) (null? h))` you cannot be sure it's a pair since the only thing you checked was if any were null. Try `(removesub* '(a b c) 10)` or `(removesub* 'symbol '(a b c))` to see the difference.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind taking a look at [my latest question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544606/remove-subsequence-function-deep-recursion-in-scheme-using-cps) about the problem?

Comment: @stack_pooper I see Chris has already answered. In DrRacket in both `#!racket` and `#!r6rs` it throws an error about `con` but not the missing parentheses since `cond` terms has explicit `begin` and the missing parentheses only change the code without it being an error. In the teaching languages, eg. `Advanced student with lambda`, it will throw an error if explicit `begin` is used as an error but you have to  add `(define pair? cons?)` to the top since they have chosen symmetry over history.