# Remove subsequence function (deep recursion) in Scheme using CPS

Tags: recursion, scheme, lisp

`removesub*` takes a list of atoms and a general list. The first list is a subsequence of the second list. The method should return the second list with the first occurence of the subsequence removed. So, if the first list is '(a b c), the first a if the second list is removed, the first b that appears after the removed a is removed, and the first c that appears after the removed b is removed - no matter how deep the atoms are nested.

> (removesub* '(a b) '(w (x b) ((a) ((y z))) b))
>
> Expected Output:
>   (w (x b) (() ((y z))))

I am trying to complete this function using continuous passing style (CPS). This is really difficult for me to grasp with a function of this complexity. [With the help of a previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461929/remove-subsequence-function-deep-recursion-in-scheme), I was able to attempt the problem, **but my attempt returns an empty list**.

What am I doing wrong?

### Attempt

```
(define removesub*
  (lambda (l1 l2 return)
    (cond
      ((or (not (pair? l1)) (not (pair? l2))) return l1 l2)
      ((pair? (car l2))
       (removesub* l1
                   (car l2)
                   (lambda (v1 v2car)
                     (removesub* v1
                                 (cdr l2)
                                 (lambda (v1 v2cdr)
                                   (return v1 (cons v2car v2cdr)))))))
      ((eq? (car l1) (car l2))
       (removesub* (cdr l1) (cdr l2) return))
      (else
       (removesub* l1
                   (cdr l2)
                   (lambda (v1 v2)
                     (return v1 (con (car l2) v2))))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With two small changes to your code, I got something to work:

1. I changed `return l1 l2` to `(return l1 l2)` in the first `cond` branch.
2. I changed `con` to `cons` in the bottom line.

Good luck!

Comment: Ughhhhh so frustrating that theres no error message thats gonna point something out like that! Thanks!